# What is KEY_WOW64_RES?

Tags: winapi

In the windows headers, there are

```
//
// Registry Specific Access Rights.
//

#define KEY_QUERY_VALUE         (0x0001)
#define KEY_SET_VALUE           (0x0002)
#define KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY      (0x0004)
#define KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS  (0x0008)
#define KEY_NOTIFY              (0x0010)
#define KEY_CREATE_LINK         (0x0020)
#define KEY_WOW64_32KEY         (0x0200)
#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY         (0x0100)
#define KEY_WOW64_RES           (0x0300)
```

These are all well documented in the MSDN article, [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878.aspx/html), except
`KEY_WOW64_RES`. What does this mean? It appears to turn on contradictory flags.

Comment: @user: That doesn't make sense. If you're calling `RegCreateKeyEx`, then the key has to be created *somewhere*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KEY_WOW64_RES` is a combination of both `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` and `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.  It is useful for masking out WOW64 bits, such as when you need to make changes to a existing rights mask but want to preserve the WOW64 bits.

For example, you can `AND` a mask with `KEY_WOW64_RES` to retrieve its existing WOW64 bits, mask out `KEY_WOW64_RES` from the new mask, and then `OR` the original WOW64 bits into the new mask, eg:

```
REGSAM Rights = ...;
REGSAM Wow64Rights = rights & KEY_WOW64_RES;
Rights = (NewRights & ~KEY_WOW64_RES) | Wow64Rights;
```

One library I know uses `KEY_WOW64_RES` when attempting to open a Registry key for read-only access using less restrictive rights each time it fails:

```
// Preserve KEY_WOW64_XXX flags for later use
WOWFlags = FAccess & KEY_WOW64_RES;

Result = RegOpenKeyEx(..., KEY_READ | WOWFlags, ...);
if (Result == 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    Result = RegOpenKeyEx(..., STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | WOWFlags, ...);
    if (Result == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        Result = RegOpenKeyEx(..., KEY_QUERY_VALUE | WOWFlags, ...);
        if (Result == 0)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so maybe `_RES` means "reserved". +1

Comment: But then, if it means "reserved", it's probably not meant for masking and there's no guarantee it will still be defined in the future... If you really need to mask the WOW64 bits, it makes more sense to simply OR them together.